# EventListener Fires Right Away Unless Wrapped In Anonymous Function Which Then Prevents RemoveEventListener

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I seem to be stuck.

I have the following event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',scrollEventListener(scope,element,attrs,WallService,$state))
```

If I do this it runs right away, even without a scroll.

So I wrapped it:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){scrollEventListener(scope,element,attrs,WallService,$state)})
```

But now I can't reference it with:

```
window.removeEventListener("scroll",scrollEventListener);
```

How can I add an eventlistner properly that won't fire right away that I can still reference so that I can remove the listener.

I am using AngularJS and want to remove the listener because it should only exist with the directive, i.e. it goes like this:

```
    scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll",scrollEventListener);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you were calling it instead. try this:

```
var scrollEvent = function(){scrollEventListener (<call with args>)};
```

OR

```
var scrollEvent = scrollEventListener.bind(this, <args separate by comma>)
```

and then

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',scrollEvent );
......
......
window.removeEventListener('scroll',scrollEvent );
```

would be enough

Comment: How about the arguments I need to pass?